# How to compare properties in backbone.js?

Tags: javascript, backbone.js

I have 2 models, in each model consist of ParentId. i need to compare these parentId's, if
      parentId's are eqval then i need to display the Name of the 2nd parentId

for ex,
1st model

```
{
  defaults: {
    ParentID : ' ',  
  }
}
```

2nd model,

```
{
  defaults: {
    ParentID : '   ',
    Name:'',
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
if (model1.get("ParentID") === model2.get("ParentID")) {
    console.log(model2.get("Name"));
}
```

Obviously first you have to create some model. In the code above you are only trying to extend Backbone.Model. So it should be

```
var Person = Backbone.Model.extend({
  defaults: {
    "parentID":  123,
    "name":     ""
  }
});

var p1 = new Person({"name": "p1"}),
    p2 = new Person({"name": "p2"});

if (p1.get("parentID") === p2.get("parentID")) {
    console.log(p2.get("name"));
}
```

**Edit**:
If you want to check whether model has `parentID` do `model.has("parentID");`

Answer (score 0):

```
var reducedCollection = _.difference(this.firstCollection.toJSON(),this.secondCollection.toJSON());
```

Comment: He wants to compare properties not whole models.

Answer (score 0):

```
function getName (model1, model2) {
    return model1.get('ParentID') === model2.get('ParentID') ? model2.get('name') : model1.get('name');
}
```

Comment: It would be nice if you explained your code a bit. Cheers :)